# How can I move the entire home folder and sub folders and files from an account to another account in the same Synology NAS?

Tags: file, move, account, file-sharing, synology

I made a mistake putting files in the admin home folder. I want to move that info to another account (non admin user).

How can I move the entire home folder and sub folders and files from the admin account to another account (non admin) in the same Synology NAS?